# TaskCanceledException on azure function (Service bus trigger)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a Service Bus Trigger Azure function, which is triggered every time a topic receives a message.
Messages arrive at regular intervals, for example every 30 minutes. Between lots, no activity.

The function does nothing special, it does an asynchronous posting of the message via HttpClient. The function is regularly stopped with a TaskCanceledException.

The HttpClient is static

```
public static class SampleEventTrigger
{
    private static DefaultHttpWebHook webHook = new DefaultHttpWebHook(new Uri("https://nonexistent.invalid/sampleWebHook"), "/event/sampleEvent");

    [FunctionName("SampleEventTrigger")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("sampleevent", "SampleEvent.Subs", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = GlobalConfiguration.ServiceBusConnection)]BrokeredMessage message,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("launch sample event subscription");

        try
        {
            var resp = await webHook.Post(message, log);
            log.Info($"{resp.StatusCode}, {resp.ReasonPhrase}");                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error($"exception in webhook: {ex.Message}", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

If I raise it again just after, this time it passes.
Where does this exception come from? How do we avoid that?
Is it related to a timeout, or to launching the function that would be too slow?

My function is in Consumption mode.

Comment: Why are you awaiting on Task.CompletedTask by the way? You can remove that line :)

Comment: sure, it's just a quick copy and paste  code to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Can you provide the following information? 1) The region your function app is deployed in, 2) function app name ([you can share privately](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)), and 3) timeframe within which this happened (in UTC for preference.)

Comment: Hello, Id=a27b04cd-7ce4-4a11-b8ed-e145fc9eabae region is West Europe, timestamp : 2018-07-18T09:30:00.193Z

Comment: I get a similar `TaskCancelledException` with an empty inner exception. Though in my case, I'm using a `TimerTrigger`. I think this is related to the method being async.

Comment: Yes, i use a timerTrigger with async methods too to send messages to the service bus. I have change the trigger , instead of sending messages every 30min, it send messages every 10 minutes, and now i do not have problems. I think the problem is a wake up one on Azure Functions with async calls

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your Http call is timing out. Awaited Http calls that time out throw TaskCanceledException . I'm not sure what your DefaultHttpWebHook class does under the covers, but it should be using [PostAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync(v=vs.118).aspx) in the `Post` method ([which itself should have the Async suffix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#BKMK_NamingConvention)).

To verify you could catch TaskCanceledException and examine the inner exception. If you are still struggling, convert your code to non-async during local development to get a better handle on what's happening - it'll give you back a true exception rather than bubbling it up as a TCE.

Comment: DefaultHttpWebHook  is just a wrapper around httpclient, and yes post make a PostAsync call

Comment: No the inner exception is empty and the exception occurs before any timeout, after less than a second of execution

Comment: Ok, I've updated my advice and removed the code which doesn't fit your scenario the way I thought it might

Comment: No, i think the problem is a wake up of the functions after 30 minutes of inactivity, with async calls in the functions